# How to find text and/or tags after element? (Jquery, JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery 3.4.1.

I have a html form which contains elements like this. This is placed

```
<section id=question1>
<input name=A type=radio value=1>Some text (Some text)
<input name=A type=radio value=2><i>Some text</i>
<u class=somewrapper><input name=A type=radio value=3><i>Some text<i> (Some text)</u>
<u class=somewrapper><input name=A type=radio value=4><i><em>Some text</em><i> (Some text)</u>
<u class=somewrapper><input name=A type=radio value=5><u><em>Some text</em><u> (Some text)</u>
</section>
```

I would like to get the text value after the input text I have selected.

```
$("input[type='radio']").on("click", function(){
    var allInputs = $(this).parent().find("input");
    var Chk = $(allInputs).filter("input:checked");
    console.log($(Chk).find(text=true));
    });
```

I need to get the things (being it tags or empty text) which are between the selected input and next input or end of this section.

When first input selected the result could be `array[0] = "Some text (Some text)"`
When second input selected the result could be the `array[0] = object with i tag containing the text`.
When third input selected the result could be like `array[0] = object with i tag containing text "Some text"` and `array[1] = object with a text "(Some text)"` (or something like this)

I have also tryied to get the following elements:

```
console.log( $(Chk).NextAll() );
```

But I got error in Chrome (49.0.2623.112 m), NextAll is not a function.

Note:
*The purpose why I want to search the text after input is that I want to modify the text when user of mobile device clicked on radio box. I want to hide the text or make it shorter, when the option has been selected and make the displayed text taking less space on a small screen. This is not subject of discusion, I just want to explain why I am trying to find the texts which are followed by the input tag.*

Comment: `NextAll` should be `nextAll`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

What about tagging the text associated to the input element with a similar class?

It's really tough to use css selectors here because of how inconsistent the layout is.

Then use:

```
$("input[type='radio']").on("click", function(){
   let val = this.value;
   let allText = $(`.label-${val}`);
   let trimmedText = [];
   for(let text of allText) {
    trimmedText.push($(text).html().trim());
   }
   let concatText = trimmedText.join(' ');
   console.log(concatText)
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/uf0ejcso/

Comment: May you please explain me the meaning of this? `.label-${val}`

Comment: This is replaced to .label-1, .label-2 ... .label-n depending on what val is - which is the value of the clicked input button here

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have a consistent HTML structure and it would be easier. However, You could try something like this:

```
$("input[type='radio']").on("click", function() {
    var outputText = [];
    var current = this.nextSibling;
    while (current !== null && current.tagName !== "INPUT") {
        if (current.tagName) { //Check if element or node
            outputText.push(current.innerText)
        } else {
            outputText.push(current.nodeValue)
        }
        current = current.nextSibling;
    }
});
```

One limitation is that for an element such as `<u class=somewrapper><input name=A type=radio value=3><i>Some text</i> (Some text)</u>` it would add "Some text" and "(Some text)" while scanning the element as well as scanning the node (causing duplication). You can further optimize this by checking if the current element contains child elements and processing the child elements instead.